# How would I go about calling a function inside a c program that I wrote using x64 nasm?

Tags: c, assembly, opengl

I'm trying to make an opengl binding for my compiler that compiles a programming to asm, and I need to know how to call a function side of compiled c code in asm. I'm using gnu/linux and I don't care about being cross platform

I've tried googling it but most of it is about how to use printf inside of asm

Comment: Assuming you followed the calling convention when you wrote the function (and you exported it) you just call it as usual. The compiler does not care whether you wrote a function in C or assembly.

Comment: You don't need a `_start`. You need your function. `_start` is the entry point of the program and that is already defined by the C library code which then calls your `main`.

Answer (score 2):

If you link or C with the assembly object file you can use the syntax

```
    extern int your_function();
```

to import it from the object file.
assembly:

```
; test.asm
global your_function
your_function:
mov eax, 500 ; return 500
ret
```

then use the above syntax to use that function.